# Calculate CPU usage from top command in linux

Tags: linux, command, cpu, cpu-usage

I have to display the CPU usage on my application and update it in real time. I am using top command to get the CPU usage i.e. [image: top command]

I add the two highlighted values to get the CPU usage. The command which i am using to add the highlighted values and get the final CPU usage is:

```
top -b -n 2 | grep Cpu | awk '{printf "CPU Load:%.2f\n", $(NF-13) + $(NF-15)}' | sed -n '2 p'
```

Issues is that, this command stops working after sometime i.e. for 3-4 minutes i do get the CPU usage but after that command does not process and i do not get the updated value. I am running this command in a loop.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using /proc filesystem. You can find there all the `top` information and much more. For example in /proc/PID/sched file.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the similar script without issues for some time now:

```
top -bn2 | grep Cpu | tail -n1 | sed -e 's/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/' | awk '{print 100-$1}'
```

The script takes the 'idle' time from top output and deduct it from 100% to get cpu usage.

The periodicity of the loop in which you are calling the script should not be faster than the time needed for the script to finish. Otherwise, you may get multiple 'top's running in parallel. This primarily depends on the 'top' default delay on your system, on mine, it is about 5s, but you can set this with -d switch.

Comment: thanks that worked :), but now i have another issue, my application does not update in real time i.e. top command has refreshed 5-6 times and my application is only refreshed once. how can i sync my application usage with top command ? @mnikolic